# Run SelectLayerByAttribute for multiple where clauses

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have around 20 different where clauses that I will need to run it at different times when my dataset is updated. Is there a way to iterate through a list of where clauses and get the results, so I don't have to type each one out separately in the code?

This is what I have so far (just testing it by putting 3 of the where clauses in the list for now). The script at the moment is successfully calling the where1 clauses but I don't know how to get it to loop through the others. Assuming I need to use a for loop but not exactly sure how?

The print statement also gives me the entire SQL statement but I'm happy to figure that out later.

```
import arcpy

dataset = r"F:\DB_Intersect_200213"

where1 = "management_type IN ('1', '7') AND year IS NOT NULL AND habitat IS NOT NULL"
where2 = "management_type IN ('1', '7') AND year IS NULL AND habitat IS NOT NULL"
where3 = "management_type IN ('1', '7') AND year IS NOT NULL AND habitat IS NULL"

wherelist = [where1, where2, where3]

featurelayer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(dataset, "data_fl")
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(featurelayer, "NEW_SELECTION", wherelist[0])
expressioncount = arcpy.GetCount_management(selection).getOutput(0)
print("There are {} results for " + wherelist[0]).format(expressioncount)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand you completely, but how about this,

```
for i in range(len(wherelist)):
    selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(
        featurelayer,
        "NEW_SELECTION",
        wherelist[i]
    )
    expressioncount = arcpy.GetCount_management(selection).getOutput(0)
    print("There are {} results for {}".format(expressioncount, wherelist[i]))
```